# Automation testing UI using Instruments - iOS

Tags: ios, instruments, uicollectionview, ios-ui-automation

I have an iPad app and I am writing automation tests for it. I tap on mainButton and it opens up a view controller. This view controller has UICollectionView in it with two cells. Each of the cell has a button and a label. I need to tap on these buttons inside the cells.

I have written code until tapping on main button and it is working. I am unable to retrieve the collection view. Here is my code.

```
....
mainButton.tap(); //This is successful.
var collectionViews = mainButton.collectionViews()["Abc"];'
app.delay(1);
collectionViews.logElementTree();   //This displays UIAElementNil

var collectionCells = collectionViews.cells();
collectionCells.logElementTree();
```

Abc is the name that I have given as restorationId for the collection view in my story board.

I think even before the view controller is loaded, I am trying to access the collectionView in it and because of this it is returning UIElementNil. Any idea on how to wait until the view controller is loaded ? I cannot import Tuneup.js into my project.

Any input on this would be of great help.

Comment: On that second line, it looks like you're asking the `mainButton` for it's collection view. Are you sure that's right? Are you nesting collection views inside of button controls?

Comment: Got it...that was the mistake I am doing. Thank you Jonathan Penn :)